# Error Wso2 "Problem accessing: /. Reason: Not Found" when I try to log in Api Manager after configure Api Analytics

Tags: wso2, analytics, api-manager

I've installed Wso2 Api Manager a few days ago follow this intructions:
1. I've downloaded https://wso2.com/api-management/install.
2. I've installed using the wizard in C:\Program Files\WSO2\API Manager directory.
3. I've initialize Api Manger console, then created some apis from https://localhost:9443/publisher .

Now, I want to see some statistics (https://192.168.138.117:9443/publisher/site/pages/all-statistics.jag?page=api-usage-user&stat=all-stat). I've read that API Analytics has to be configured, so I carried out the following steps (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+APIM+Analytics#ConfiguringAPIMAnalytics-Step1-DownloadandinstallWSO2API-M).

1. I download it (https://wso2.com/api-management/install/analytics).
2. Unzip file in C:\WSO2\wso2am-analytics-2.6.0.
3. I've created and Environment Variables called JAVA_HOME. In value field, I typed the installation path of the Java Development Kit, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191.
4. I edited the tag true in the file "C:\Program Files\WSO2\API Manager\2.6.0\repository\conf\api-manager.xml".
5. I exec this command in cmd windows: "C:\WSO2\wso2am-analytics-2.6.0>worker.bat -run". It excecuted some process and aparentely everything was ok.
6. Finally, I run another windows console and exec: "C:\Program Files\WSO2\API Manager\2.6.0\bin>wso2server.bat -run".

Now, when I try to log in https://localhost:9443/publisher, /store o /carbon, I'm getting this error:

> Problem accessing: /. Reason: Not Found

If I only lunch the Api Manager, it works perfectly but I can't get the statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow Quick setup?
To access Analytics you need to carry out Standard Setup which includes:

1. Creating Analytics DB with the "am_usage_uploaded_files" table in addition
2. Configuring /conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml --> APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
3. Configuring /conf/worker/deployment.yaml --> APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
4. Configure /conf/worker/deployment.yaml --> WSO2AM_MGW_ANALYTICS_DB

And then starting the worker which creates the rest tables for analytics.